# How do Applications are being notified by Gemfire

Tags: spring, spring-integration, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

In a web application that uses Gemfire to store their Session (Spring Session - an implementation of HTTPSession), how does Gemfire notify the changes (like cache expiry, cache change, cache destry..events) ? especially when Gemfire is deployed in a Client-Server model or Peer-to-Peer model..etc. the event might get triggered in any one node in the entire distributed environment, we might not want to keep listening to all the nodes..etc.

I see Gemfire has MBeans which emits notifications, should our application hook listeners to these MBean notifications or is there any other better way ?

The purpose is to put some clean-up code during such events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the GemFire event listener model approach whereby each node would listen for events (poll - sorta), rather than have the source 'push' to each node.  in GemFire, have a look at the `ContinuousQueryListener` ([Spring Integration Example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/gemfire.html) or [Spring Data GemFire docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#apis:cq-container)) to enable you to subscribe to events.